# TabBarController, TabBarItems not show correctly

Tags: ios, interface-builder

This is what my TabBarController looks like:
[image]

You can see that the TabBarItem is missing. It shows correctly before, but I don't know when becomes this. In simulator, it shows correctly, but not in storyboard.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried erasing those views and adding new ones? 
Sometimes the view in the storyboard doest load correctly but when you ad new ones it works.

Comment: I tried, no help. But it works fine if I create a new project.